# Violate the method that checks a list of generic objects

Tags: java, generics, jvm, type-erasure

This is a task from [Hyperskill.org](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/4894).

The instructions for the task are;

> You need to add implementation to Violator.defraud() method that will
>   do the following:
>
> ﻿Create List of Boxes according to method signature
>   Put Paper object in at least one Box in the list The resulting list
>   should pass NaiveQualityControl check You shouldn't change method
>   signature or change code of any other classes, just add implementaiton
>   to defraud method.

```
/* This class and its subclasses should pass quality check */
class Bakery {}

class Cake extends Bakery {}

/* But this should not */
class Paper {}

/* These boxes are used to pack stuff */
class Box<T> {
    void put(T item) { /* implementation omitted */ }
    T get() { /* implementation omitted */ }
}

/* This quality checker ensures that boxes for sale contain Bakery and anything else */
class NaiveQualityControl {

  public static boolean check(List<Box<? extends Bakery>> boxes) {
    /* Method signature guarantees that all illegal 
       calls will produce compile-time error... or not? */  
    return true;  
  }

}
```

This is the method to implement;

```
class Violator {

    public static List<Box<? extends Bakery>> defraud() {
        // Add implementation here
    }

}
```

So far I have got this;

```
public static List<Box<? extends Bakery>> defraud() {
        List<Box<? extends Bakery>> boxList = new ArrayList<>();

        Box<Paper> paperBox = new Box<>();
        Box<Bakery> bakeryBox = new Box<>();
        Box<Cake> cakeBox = new Box<>();

        boxList.add(bakeryBox);
        boxList.add(cakeBox);
        boxList.add(paperBox); // compile time error, required type <? extends Bakery>

        return boxList;
    }
```

Obviously this won't run. I have tried using `Object` as a type but that is out of type bounds for `<? extends Bakery>`. I can't cast a `paperBox` to a `<? extends Bakery` `Box` type.

Comment: Hint: it doesn't say anything about the code having to compile without a warning about using unchecked or unsafe operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around it by using [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) (by dropping the generics for `boxList`). In fact, if you do this, you can add just about any type of `Object`:

```java
public List<Box<? extends Bakery>> defraud() {
    List<Box<? extends Bakery>> boxList = new ArrayList<>();

    Box<Paper> paperBox = new Box<>();
    Box<Bakery> bakeryBox = new Box<>();
    Box<Cake> cakeBox = new Box<>();

    boxList.add(bakeryBox);
    boxList.add(cakeBox);

    List rawTypedList = boxList;    // Drop the generics to use raw types. 
    rawTypedList.add(paperBox);
    rawTypedList.add(new Object()); // Acutally, you can add any object, not just Boxes.

    return boxList;
}
```

You'll get a warning from the compiler or IDE for using [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) though - it is considered [bad practice](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454).